# HTTP 500 Error when attempting to change Wordpress Site Address

Tags: wordpress

I've installed Wordpress in a subdirectory (http://example.org/wp)

Now I want the site accessible from http://example.org In WordPress settings so I edited the **Site Address (URL)** to :
http://example.org

Then, as per some instructions I've read I copied the http://example.org/wp/index.php file to http://example.org/index.php and edited the path to include the subdirectory:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . ‘/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

However, now when I visit http://example.org I just get a blank page in Safari and HTTP 500 error in Chrome.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to access the site's wp-admin area? If so, try visiting the Settings > Permalinks page and see if that fixes things for you.

Comment: @GregBurkett Yes, I can access the wp-admin page but visiting the Permalinks page did not resolve anything for me.

Comment: I did just notice that the opening single-quote in the require statement you posted above is a 'fancy' quote mark. Can you try replacing that with a standard ' ?

Comment: That was it.. thanks so much.  Not sure if should have you provide this as an answer or if I should delete this now

Comment: I'll answer it if you feel like accepting :) Glad it was something simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did just notice that the opening single-quote in the require statement you posted above is a 'fancy' quote mark. Can you try replacing that with a standard ' ?